# how to deploy or do rolling update depending on existing replication controller?

Tags: docker, kubernetes, yaml

[image: e]

I have mutiple stages in docker. I am using both rolling update and deployement. currently if nothing is deployed I have to do deploy manually and every time I update rolling update will be run by itself.

I want to automate everything. I want to write some condition to check if 
there is existing replication controller then run rolling update else run deploy. I tried to put if statements in scripts in both deploy or rollout update.

```
- >
  if rancher --debug kubectl rollout status deployment $CI_PROJECT_NAME; then
      exit 0
  fi
```

unfortunately I got error:

> ERROR: Job failed (system failure): secrets
>   "runner-yx1bv22m-project-122-concurrent-0vrbdb" is forbidden: exceeded
>   quota: default-467s2, requested: secrets=1, used: secrets=20, limited:
>   secrets=20

from what I understand I can't run both jobs at once. **what Is the right way to achieve either deployment or rolling update depending on current deployment status?**

Comment: Is this about Rancher setup, or are you directly using Kubernetes objects?

Comment: I am using kubernetes in rancher. I am not using Kubernetes directly. all my commands are rancher --debug kubectl ... .

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image]

Basically I got rid of second job. I do everything in single job now.

```
  script:
    other scripts
    - CHECK_DEPLOYMENT=$(rancher --debug kubectl --insecure-skip-tls-verify get deployments -n $CI_PROJECT_NAME-$CI_COMMIT_REF_SLUG | grep $CI_PROJECT_NAME | awk '{print $1}')
    - >
      if [ "$CHECK_DEPLOYMENT" == "$CI_PROJECT_NAME" ]; then
        do rollup script
      else
        do deploy script
      fi
```

both deployment or rollup is done by adding single if statement. depending on deployment it will do either roll up or it will deploy.